# Table of conditions seems incorrect

Tags: evaluation, table

If I enter

```
Table[Sort@IntegerDigits@x == Sort@IntegerDigits[n x], {n, 2, 6}]
```

the result is

```
{IntegerDigits[x] == IntegerDigits[2 x], 
 IntegerDigits[x] == IntegerDigits[3 x], 
 IntegerDigits[x] == IntegerDigits[4 x], 
 IntegerDigits[x] == IntegerDigits[5 x], 
 IntegerDigits[x] == IntegerDigits[6 x]}
```

What happened to the `Sort`s?

Edit: I'm trying to append these conditions as the condition in a `Select`, to make it easier to write instead of putting all of the conditions in the statement. So I would prefer not to write

```
Select[ stuff, Sort@IntegerDigits@# == Sort@IntegerDigits[2#] && ...]
```

Comment: Why do you check the equivalence of `IntegerDigits[x]` with `IntegerDigits[n x]`? What is `x`? Could you please include the desired output?

Comment: The `Sort`s evaluated, had no effect on the expressions, and do not appear in the output. If `x` has previously been given an integer value, the expressions would each evaluate to `False`.

Comment: @syed Clarified what I was *really* trying to do, which I realized I should have added in the first place.

Answer (score 4):

When `x` is undefined `IntegerDigits` returns unevaluated, and `Sort` is fine with this; it just sorts arguments of `IntegerDigits` - and since there's only one argument, sorting does nothing in this case.

If you are expecting sorting to happen only when `IntegerDigits` actually evaluates to a `List` you can do something like this:

```
ClearAll[sortList];
sortList[l_List] := Sort[l]

Table[sortList@IntegerDigits@x == sortList@IntegerDigits[n x], {n, 2, 6}]

(* {sortList[IntegerDigits[x]] == sortList[IntegerDigits[2 x]], 
    sortList[IntegerDigits[x]] == sortList[IntegerDigits[3 x]], 
    sortList[IntegerDigits[x]] == sortList[IntegerDigits[4 x]], 
    sortList[IntegerDigits[x]] == sortList[IntegerDigits[5 x]], 
    sortList[IntegerDigits[x]] == sortList[IntegerDigits[6 x]]} *)
```

Now sorting happens only when `x` has an assigned value:

```
% /. x -> 142857

(* {True, True, True, True, True} *)
```