# Generating a list of conditions for a select

Tags: evaluation, table

I would like to generate a condition for a `select` statement that looks like

```
Sort@IntegerDigits@# == Sort@IntegerDigits[2#] && 
Sort@IntegerDigits@# == Sort@IntegerDigits[3#] && ...
```

I tried asking this question before [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/282812/table-of-conditions-seems-incorrect#282812), but wasn't very clear, so I'm trying again. How can I avoid having these statements evaluated at generation time so that I can just plug in the result?

Comment: What's wrong with the [solution proposed](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/282814/27951) to your previous question using an auxiliary sorting function that only evaluates when given a list?

Answer (score 0):

```
Clear["Global`*"]
```

Define a helper function that only evaluates with a positive integer input

```
sortedDigits[x_Integer?Positive] := Sort@IntegerDigits@x

SeedRandom[1234];

sol = Select[Range[10^6],
  sortedDigits[#] == sortedDigits[2 #] &]

(* {125874, 128574, 142587, 142857, 258714, 258741, 285714, 285741, 412587, \
412857, 425871, 428571} *)
```

Checking,

```
And @@ (sortedDigits[#] == sortedDigits[2 #] & /@ sol)

(* True *)
```